# Fabrix 1.x installation issue

Tags: python, pip

I tried installing [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) but it seems I am getting this error. I have been trying to install it a system where I don't have root access and I use `pip install --user` to install packages. I even tried using `pip2` but that doesn't work either. Any clues would be appreciated.

```
$ fab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/surya/.local/bin/fab", line 7, in <module>
    from fabric.main import main
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from operator import isMappingType
ImportError: cannot import name 'isMappingType'
```

Comment: Does `/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fabric/main.py` exist?  Does it contain what it should?

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was an issue that was caused because python2 itself was not installed on the target box I was trying to execute fabric on. Thankfully I got this figured!